# Rate of change of a cubes area in respect to the space diagonal

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The space diagonal of a cube shrinks with $0.02\rm m/s$. How fast is the area shrinking when the space diagonal is $0.8\rm m$ long?

[image: Picture of Cube Diagonals (source: Wikipedia)]

I try:
Space Diagonal = $s_d = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=\sqrt{3a^2}$ Where $a$ is the length of one side.
  Area = $a^2$

Rate of change for $s_d$ with respect to $a$
$${\mathrm d\over \mathrm da}s_d={\mathrm d\over \mathrm da}\sqrt{3a^2}={\sqrt{3}a \over \sqrt{a^2}}$$

Rate of change for $\rm area$ with respect to $a$
$${\mathrm d\over \mathrm da}\mathrm{area}={\mathrm d\over \mathrm da}a^2={2a}$$

Im stuck when it comes to calculating one thing from another thing! However I have no problem when it comes to position, velocity and acceleration! Can anybody solve this?

Comment: @George: Having a link for a title is definitely *not* a good edit.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, woah, sorry, not sure how that happened.

Comment: Total area is $6a^2$, not just $a^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $dA/dt$. By the chain rule, $$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{dA}{da}\cdot\frac{da}{ds}\cdot\frac{ds}{dt}$$ which is an equation that applies at all points in time, for all sizes of the cube.

At the moment in question, you know $s$ directly. You can use algebra (no calculus) to find $a$ and $A$ at that moment too. Then you have already worked out a formula for the first factor. You have a formula for the reciprocal of the second factor. And the value of the third is a constant negative number given in the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. However Im not getting anywhere! Can you please post a solution?

Comment: Ignoring units of measure: since $s=\sqrt{3}a$, when $s=0.8$, $a=0.8/\sqrt{3}$. You have computed $dA/da=2a$, so at the moment in question $dA/da=1.6/\sqrt{3}$. That's one out of three factors...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to express the area $a$ of the cube as a function of the length $d$ of the space diagonal. Given $d$ the side length $s$ of the cube is
$$s={1\over\sqrt{3}} \ d\ ,$$
and the total surface area $a$ then becomes
$$a=6s^2=2 d^2\ .$$
Now all quantities appearing here are in fact functions of $t$; therefore at all times $t$ we have
$$a(t)=2d^2(t)\ .$$
It follows that
$$a'(t)=4d (t) \ d'(t)\ ,$$
and the data $d(t_0)=0.8$ m, $d'(t_0)=-0.02$ m/sec imply that $a'(t_0)=-0.064$ m$^2$/sec.